# display highchart with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i need to populate highchart from data received from google analytics, i have the data in the following format

```
data: [[Date.UTC(2017,8,1),10],[Date.UTC(2017,8,2),1],[Date.UTC(2017,8,3),1],[Date.UTC(2017,8,4),3],[Date.UTC(2017,8,5),6],[Date.UTC(2017,8,6),3],[Date.UTC(2017,8,7),4],[Date.UTC(2017,8,8),4],[Date.UTC(2017,8,9),0],[Date.UTC(2017,8,10),4],[Date.UTC(2017,8,11),9],[Date.UTC(2017,8,12),4],[Date.UTC(2017,8,13),6],[Date.UTC(2017,8,14),7],[Date.UTC(2017,8,15),5],[Date.UTC(2017,8,16),3],[Date.UTC(2017,8,17),3],[Date.UTC(2017,8,18),12],[Date.UTC(2017,8,19),8],[Date.UTC(2017,8,20),6],[Date.UTC(2017,8,21),6],[Date.UTC(2017,8,22),1],[Date.UTC(2017,8,23),1],[Date.UTC(2017,8,24),3],[Date.UTC(2017,8,25),6],[Date.UTC(2017,8,26),3],[Date.UTC(2017,8,27),4],[Date.UTC(2017,8,28),12],[Date.UTC(2017,8,29),5],[Date.UTC(2017,8,30),2],[Date.UTC(2017,9,1),0],[Date.UTC(2017,9,2),9],[Date.UTC(2017,9,3),7],[Date.UTC(2017,9,4),11],[Date.UTC(2017,9,5),10],[Date.UTC(2017,9,6),11],[Date.UTC(2017,9,7),4],[Date.UTC(2017,9,8),4],[Date.UTC(2017,9,9),16],[Date.UTC(2017,9,10),4],[Date.UTC(2017,9,11),7],[Date.UTC(2017,9,12),5],[Date.UTC(2017,9,13),10],[Date.UTC(2017,9,14),3],[Date.UTC(2017,9,15),1],[Date.UTC(2017,9,16),21],[Date.UTC(2017,9,17),7],[Date.UTC(2017,9,18),14],[Date.UTC(2017,9,19),9],[Date.UTC(2017,9,20),11],[Date.UTC(2017,9,21),3],[Date.UTC(2017,9,22),3],[Date.UTC(2017,9,23),25],[Date.UTC(2017,9,24),7],[Date.UTC(2017,9,25),9],[Date.UTC(2017,9,26),11],[Date.UTC(2017,9,27),18],[Date.UTC(2017,9,28),4],[Date.UTC(2017,9,29),2],[Date.UTC(2017,9,30),10],[Date.UTC(2017,9,31),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,1),5],[Date.UTC(2017,10,2),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,3),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,4),5],[Date.UTC(2017,10,5),6],[Date.UTC(2017,10,6),1],[Date.UTC(2017,10,7),6],[Date.UTC(2017,10,8),6],[Date.UTC(2017,10,9),3],[Date.UTC(2017,10,10),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,11),2],[Date.UTC(2017,10,12),1],[Date.UTC(2017,10,13),1],[Date.UTC(2017,10,14),8],[Date.UTC(2017,10,15),8],[Date.UTC(2017,10,16),6],[Date.UTC(2017,10,17),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,18),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,19),1],[Date.UTC(2017,10,20),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,21),5],[Date.UTC(2017,10,22),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,23),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,24),1],[Date.UTC(2017,10,25),5],[Date.UTC(2017,10,26),2],[Date.UTC(2017,10,27),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,28),2],[Date.UTC(2017,10,29),10],[Date.UTC(2017,10,30),2],[Date.UTC(2017,11,1),4],[Date.UTC(2017,11,2),5],[Date.UTC(2017,11,3),3],[Date.UTC(2017,11,4),2],[Date.UTC(2017,11,5),7],[Date.UTC(2017,11,6),2],[Date.UTC(2017,11,7),3],[Date.UTC(2017,11,8),10],[Date.UTC(2017,11,9),1],[Date.UTC(2017,11,10),0],[Date.UTC(2017,11,11),6],[Date.UTC(2017,11,12),3],[Date.UTC(2017,11,13),4],[Date.UTC(2017,11,14),5],[Date.UTC(2017,11,15),3],[Date.UTC(2017,11,16),3],[Date.UTC(2017,11,17),0],[Date.UTC(2017,11,18),1],[Date.UTC(2017,11,19),1],[Date.UTC(2017,11,20),8],[Date.UTC(2017,11,21),9],[Date.UTC(2017,11,22),3],[Date.UTC(2017,11,23),1],[Date.UTC(2017,11,24),4],[Date.UTC(2017,11,25),1],[Date.UTC(2017,11,26),6],[Date.UTC(2017,11,27),7],[Date.UTC(2017,11,28),3],[Date.UTC(2017,11,29),3],[Date.UTC(2017,11,30),0],[Date.UTC(2017,11,31),5],[Date.UTC(2018,0,1),2],[Date.UTC(2018,0,2),2],[Date.UTC(2018,0,3),5],[Date.UTC(2018,0,4),10],[Date.UTC(2018,0,5),16],[Date.UTC(2018,0,6),2],[Date.UTC(2018,0,7),0],[Date.UTC(2018,0,8),4],[Date.UTC(2018,0,9),4],[Date.UTC(2018,0,10),2],[Date.UTC(2018,0,11),3],[Date.UTC(2018,0,12),2],[Date.UTC(2018,0,13),4],[Date.UTC(2018,0,14),3],[Date.UTC(2018,0,15),5],[Date.UTC(2018,0,16),17],[Date.UTC(2018,0,17),18],[Date.UTC(2018,0,18),13],[Date.UTC(2018,0,19),9],[Date.UTC(2018,0,20),7],[Date.UTC(2018,0,21),2],[Date.UTC(2018,0,22),16],[Date.UTC(2018,0,23),19],[Date.UTC(2018,0,24),24],[Date.UTC(2018,0,25),23],[Date.UTC(2018,0,26),33],[Date.UTC(2018,0,27),13],[Date.UTC(2018,0,28),1],[Date.UTC(2018,0,29),11],[Date.UTC(2018,0,30),27],[Date.UTC(2018,0,31),48],[Date.UTC(2018,1,1),23],[Date.UTC(2018,1,2),24],[Date.UTC(2018,1,3),9],[Date.UTC(2018,1,4),1],[Date.UTC(2018,1,5),6],[Date.UTC(2018,1,6),20],[Date.UTC(2018,1,7),22],[Date.UTC(2018,1,8),22],[Date.UTC(2018,1,9),16],[Date.UTC(2018,1,10),9],[Date.UTC(2018,1,11),8],[Date.UTC(2018,1,12),18],[Date.UTC(2018,1,13),11],[Date.UTC(2018,1,14),20],[Date.UTC(2018,1,15),14],[Date.UTC(2018,1,16),14],[Date.UTC(2018,1,17),15],[Date.UTC(2018,1,18),5],[Date.UTC(2018,1,19),14],[Date.UTC(2018,1,20),25],[Date.UTC(2018,1,21),17],[Date.UTC(2018,1,22),23],[Date.UTC(2018,1,23),20],[Date.UTC(2018,1,24),4],[Date.UTC(2018,1,25),6],[Date.UTC(2018,1,26),22],[Date.UTC(2018,1,27),21],[Date.UTC(2018,1,28),23],[Date.UTC(2018,2,1),15],[Date.UTC(2018,2,2),8],[Date.UTC(2018,2,3),6],[Date.UTC(2018,2,4),6],[Date.UTC(2018,2,5),20],[Date.UTC(2018,2,6),24],[Date.UTC(2018,2,7),36],[Date.UTC(2018,2,8),33],[Date.UTC(2018,2,9),41],[Date.UTC(2018,2,10),20],[Date.UTC(2018,2,11),34],[Date.UTC(2018,2,12),29],[Date.UTC(2018,2,13),14],[Date.UTC(2018,2,14),36],[Date.UTC(2018,2,15),31],[Date.UTC(2018,2,16),21],[Date.UTC(2018,2,17),9],[Date.UTC(2018,2,18),6],[Date.UTC(2018,2,19),21],[Date.UTC(2018,2,20),18],[Date.UTC(2018,2,21),25],[Date.UTC(2018,2,22),13],[Date.UTC(2018,2,23),10],[Date.UTC(2018,2,24),8],[Date.UTC(2018,2,25),1],[Date.UTC(2018,2,26),7],[Date.UTC(2018,2,27),7],[Date.UTC(2018,2,28),5],[Date.UTC(2018,2,29),14],[Date.UTC(2018,2,30),1],[Date.UTC(2018,2,31),1],[Date.UTC(2018,3,1),2],[Date.UTC(2018,3,2),17],[Date.UTC(2018,3,3),6],[Date.UTC(2018,3,4),21],[Date.UTC(2018,3,5),7],[Date.UTC(2018,3,6),12],[Date.UTC(2018,3,7),5],[Date.UTC(2018,3,8),6],[Date.UTC(2018,3,9),6],[Date.UTC(2018,3,10),8],[Date.UTC(2018,3,11),17],[Date.UTC(2018,3,12),7],[Date.UTC(2018,3,13),10],[Date.UTC(2018,3,14),5],[Date.UTC(2018,3,15),4],[Date.UTC(2018,3,16),4],[Date.UTC(2018,3,17),7],[Date.UTC(2018,3,18),9],[Date.UTC(2018,3,19),11],[Date.UTC(2018,3,20),11],[Date.UTC(2018,3,21),7],[Date.UTC(2018,3,22),1],[Date.UTC(2018,3,23),13],[Date.UTC(2018,3,24),16],[Date.UTC(2018,3,25),11],[Date.UTC(2018,3,26),29],[Date.UTC(2018,3,27),12],[Date.UTC(2018,3,28),4],[Date.UTC(2018,3,29),2],[Date.UTC(2018,3,30),22],[Date.UTC(2018,4,1),6],[Date.UTC(2018,4,2),18],[Date.UTC(2018,4,3),15],[Date.UTC(2018,4,4),21],[Date.UTC(2018,4,5),6],[Date.UTC(2018,4,6),3],[Date.UTC(2018,4,7),13],[Date.UTC(2018,4,8),10],[Date.UTC(2018,4,9),23],[Date.UTC(2018,4,10),21],[Date.UTC(2018,4,11),22],[Date.UTC(2018,4,12),14],[Date.UTC(2018,4,13),1],[Date.UTC(2018,4,14),12],[Date.UTC(2018,4,15),19],[Date.UTC(2018,4,16),25],[Date.UTC(2018,4,17),20],[Date.UTC(2018,4,18),17],[Date.UTC(2018,4,19),6],[Date.UTC(2018,4,20),3],[Date.UTC(2018,4,21),4],[Date.UTC(2018,4,22),6],[Date.UTC(2018,4,23),7],[Date.UTC(2018,4,24),10],[Date.UTC(2018,4,25),11],[Date.UTC(2018,4,26),7],[Date.UTC(2018,4,27),2],[Date.UTC(2018,4,28),7],[Date.UTC(2018,4,29),7],[Date.UTC(2018,4,30),10],[Date.UTC(2018,4,31),15],[Date.UTC(2018,5,1),16],[Date.UTC(2018,5,2),9],[Date.UTC(2018,5,3),4],[Date.UTC(2018,5,4),20],[Date.UTC(2018,5,5),14],[Date.UTC(2018,5,6),13],[Date.UTC(2018,5,7),4],[Date.UTC(2018,5,8),16],[Date.UTC(2018,5,9),3],[Date.UTC(2018,5,10),2],[Date.UTC(2018,5,11),9],[Date.UTC(2018,5,12),4],[Date.UTC(2018,5,13),12],[Date.UTC(2018,5,14),7],[Date.UTC(2018,5,15),3],[Date.UTC(2018,5,16),6],[Date.UTC(2018,5,17),2],[Date.UTC(2018,5,18),10],[Date.UTC(2018,5,19),26],[Date.UTC(2018,5,20),6],[Date.UTC(2018,5,21),6],[Date.UTC(2018,5,22),4],[Date.UTC(2018,5,23),12],[Date.UTC(2018,5,24),4],[Date.UTC(2018,5,25),4],[Date.UTC(2018,5,26),6],[Date.UTC(2018,5,27),8],[Date.UTC(2018,5,28),6],[Date.UTC(2018,5,29),8],[Date.UTC(2018,5,30),8],[Date.UTC(2018,6,1),5],[Date.UTC(2018,6,2),4],[Date.UTC(2018,6,3),5],[Date.UTC(2018,6,4),4],[Date.UTC(2018,6,5),3],[Date.UTC(2018,6,6),18],[Date.UTC(2018,6,7),6],[Date.UTC(2018,6,8),3],[Date.UTC(2018,6,9),16],[Date.UTC(2018,6,10),3],[Date.UTC(2018,6,11),11],[Date.UTC(2018,6,12),20],[Date.UTC(2018,6,13),21],[Date.UTC(2018,6,14),1],[Date.UTC(2018,6,15),4],[Date.UTC(2018,6,16),9],[Date.UTC(2018,6,17),12],[Date.UTC(2018,6,18),7],[Date.UTC(2018,6,19),4],[Date.UTC(2018,6,20),6],[Date.UTC(2018,6,21),4],[Date.UTC(2018,6,22),3],[Date.UTC(2018,6,23),6],[Date.UTC(2018,6,24),4],[Date.UTC(2018,6,25),9],[Date.UTC(2018,6,26),10],[Date.UTC(2018,6,27),5],[Date.UTC(2018,6,28),6],[Date.UTC(2018,6,29),7],[Date.UTC(2018,6,30),33],[Date.UTC(2018,6,31),9],[Date.UTC(2018,7,1),3],[Date.UTC(2018,7,2),8],[Date.UTC(2018,7,3),13],[Date.UTC(2018,7,4),7],[Date.UTC(2018,7,5),3],[Date.UTC(2018,7,6),12],[Date.UTC(2018,7,7),23],[Date.UTC(2018,7,8),12],[Date.UTC(2018,7,9),8],[Date.UTC(2018,7,10),15],[Date.UTC(2018,7,11),4],[Date.UTC(2018,7,12),1],[Date.UTC(2018,7,13),4],[Date.UTC(2018,7,14),5],[Date.UTC(2018,7,15),10],[Date.UTC(2018,7,16),9],[Date.UTC(2018,7,17),6],[Date.UTC(2018,7,18),8],[Date.UTC(2018,7,19),2],[Date.UTC(2018,7,20),6],[Date.UTC(2018,7,21),13],[Date.UTC(2018,7,22),4],[Date.UTC(2018,7,23),2],[Date.UTC(2018,7,24),11],[Date.UTC(2018,7,25),3],[Date.UTC(2018,7,26),3],[Date.UTC(2018,7,27),3],[Date.UTC(2018,7,28),5],[Date.UTC(2018,7,29),5],[Date.UTC(2018,7,30),12],[Date.UTC(2018,7,31),12],[Date.UTC(2018,8,1),6]]
            };
```

i want the highchart to display data in this format please preview the below image

[image]

but when i try to add the data in my high chart configuration it doesn't support it let me show you my code

```
 var calls_chart_options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'areaspline'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            valueSuffix: ' units'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointWidth: 53
            }
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },

     data: [[Date.UTC(2017,8,1),10],[Date.UTC(2017,8,2),1],[Date.UTC(2017,8,3),1],[Date.UTC(2017,8,4),3],[Date.UTC(2017,8,5),6],[Date.UTC(2017,8,6),3],[Date.UTC(2017,8,7),4],[Date.UTC(2017,8,8),4],[Date.UTC(2017,8,9),0],[Date.UTC(2017,8,10),4],[Date.UTC(2017,8,11),9],[Date.UTC(2017,8,12),4],[Date.UTC(2017,8,13),6],[Date.UTC(2017,8,14),7],[Date.UTC(2017,8,15),5],[Date.UTC(2017,8,16),3],[Date.UTC(2017,8,17),3],[Date.UTC(2017,8,18),12],[Date.UTC(2017,8,19),8],[Date.UTC(2017,8,20),6],[Date.UTC(2017,8,21),6],[Date.UTC(2017,8,22),1],[Date.UTC(2017,8,23),1],[Date.UTC(2017,8,24),3],[Date.UTC(2017,8,25),6],[Date.UTC(2017,8,26),3],[Date.UTC(2017,8,27),4],[Date.UTC(2017,8,28),12],[Date.UTC(2017,8,29),5],[Date.UTC(2017,8,30),2],[Date.UTC(2017,9,1),0],[Date.UTC(2017,9,2),9],[Date.UTC(2017,9,3),7],[Date.UTC(2017,9,4),11],[Date.UTC(2017,9,5),10],[Date.UTC(2017,9,6),11],[Date.UTC(2017,9,7),4],[Date.UTC(2017,9,8),4],[Date.UTC(2017,9,9),16],[Date.UTC(2017,9,10),4],[Date.UTC(2017,9,11),7],[Date.UTC(2017,9,12),5],[Date.UTC(2017,9,13),10],[Date.UTC(2017,9,14),3],[Date.UTC(2017,9,15),1],[Date.UTC(2017,9,16),21],[Date.UTC(2017,9,17),7],[Date.UTC(2017,9,18),14],[Date.UTC(2017,9,19),9],[Date.UTC(2017,9,20),11],[Date.UTC(2017,9,21),3],[Date.UTC(2017,9,22),3],[Date.UTC(2017,9,23),25],[Date.UTC(2017,9,24),7],[Date.UTC(2017,9,25),9],[Date.UTC(2017,9,26),11],[Date.UTC(2017,9,27),18],[Date.UTC(2017,9,28),4],[Date.UTC(2017,9,29),2],[Date.UTC(2017,9,30),10],[Date.UTC(2017,9,31),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,1),5],[Date.UTC(2017,10,2),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,3),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,4),5],[Date.UTC(2017,10,5),6],[Date.UTC(2017,10,6),1],[Date.UTC(2017,10,7),6],[Date.UTC(2017,10,8),6],[Date.UTC(2017,10,9),3],[Date.UTC(2017,10,10),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,11),2],[Date.UTC(2017,10,12),1],[Date.UTC(2017,10,13),1],[Date.UTC(2017,10,14),8],[Date.UTC(2017,10,15),8],[Date.UTC(2017,10,16),6],[Date.UTC(2017,10,17),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,18),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,19),1],[Date.UTC(2017,10,20),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,21),5],[Date.UTC(2017,10,22),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,23),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,24),1],[Date.UTC(2017,10,25),5],[Date.UTC(2017,10,26),2],[Date.UTC(2017,10,27),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,28),2],[Date.UTC(2017,10,29),10],[Date.UTC(2017,10,30),2],[Date.UTC(2017,11,1),4],[Date.UTC(2017,11,2),5],[Date.UTC(2017,11,3),3],[Date.UTC(2017,11,4),2],[Date.UTC(2017,11,5),7],[Date.UTC(2017,11,6),2],[Date.UTC(2017,11,7),3],[Date.UTC(2017,11,8),10],[Date.UTC(2017,11,9),1],[Date.UTC(2017,11,10),0],[Date.UTC(2017,11,11),6],[Date.UTC(2017,11,12),3],[Date.UTC(2017,11,13),4],[Date.UTC(2017,11,14),5],[Date.UTC(2017,11,15),3],[Date.UTC(2017,11,16),3],[Date.UTC(2017,11,17),0],[Date.UTC(2017,11,18),1],[Date.UTC(2017,11,19),1],[Date.UTC(2017,11,20),8],[Date.UTC(2017,11,21),9],[Date.UTC(2017,11,22),3],[Date.UTC(2017,11,23),1],[Date.UTC(2017,11,24),4],[Date.UTC(2017,11,25),1],[Date.UTC(2017,11,26),6],[Date.UTC(2017,11,27),7],[Date.UTC(2017,11,28),3],[Date.UTC(2017,11,29),3],[Date.UTC(2017,11,30),0],[Date.UTC(2017,11,31),5],[Date.UTC(2018,0,1),2],[Date.UTC(2018,0,2),2],[Date.UTC(2018,0,3),5],[Date.UTC(2018,0,4),10],[Date.UTC(2018,0,5),16],[Date.UTC(2018,0,6),2],[Date.UTC(2018,0,7),0],[Date.UTC(2018,0,8),4],[Date.UTC(2018,0,9),4],[Date.UTC(2018,0,10),2],[Date.UTC(2018,0,11),3],[Date.UTC(2018,0,12),2],[Date.UTC(2018,0,13),4],[Date.UTC(2018,0,14),3],[Date.UTC(2018,0,15),5],[Date.UTC(2018,0,16),17],[Date.UTC(2018,0,17),18],[Date.UTC(2018,0,18),13],[Date.UTC(2018,0,19),9],[Date.UTC(2018,0,20),7],[Date.UTC(2018,0,21),2],[Date.UTC(2018,0,22),16],[Date.UTC(2018,0,23),19],[Date.UTC(2018,0,24),24],[Date.UTC(2018,0,25),23],[Date.UTC(2018,0,26),33],[Date.UTC(2018,0,27),13],[Date.UTC(2018,0,28),1],[Date.UTC(2018,0,29),11],[Date.UTC(2018,0,30),27],[Date.UTC(2018,0,31),48],[Date.UTC(2018,1,1),23],[Date.UTC(2018,1,2),24],[Date.UTC(2018,1,3),9],[Date.UTC(2018,1,4),1],[Date.UTC(2018,1,5),6],[Date.UTC(2018,1,6),20],[Date.UTC(2018,1,7),22],[Date.UTC(2018,1,8),22],[Date.UTC(2018,1,9),16],[Date.UTC(2018,1,10),9],[Date.UTC(2018,1,11),8],[Date.UTC(2018,1,12),18],[Date.UTC(2018,1,13),11],[Date.UTC(2018,1,14),20],[Date.UTC(2018,1,15),14],[Date.UTC(2018,1,16),14],[Date.UTC(2018,1,17),15],[Date.UTC(2018,1,18),5],[Date.UTC(2018,1,19),14],[Date.UTC(2018,1,20),25],[Date.UTC(2018,1,21),17],[Date.UTC(2018,1,22),23],[Date.UTC(2018,1,23),20],[Date.UTC(2018,1,24),4],[Date.UTC(2018,1,25),6],[Date.UTC(2018,1,26),22],[Date.UTC(2018,1,27),21],[Date.UTC(2018,1,28),23],[Date.UTC(2018,2,1),15],[Date.UTC(2018,2,2),8],[Date.UTC(2018,2,3),6],[Date.UTC(2018,2,4),6],[Date.UTC(2018,2,5),20],[Date.UTC(2018,2,6),24],[Date.UTC(2018,2,7),36],[Date.UTC(2018,2,8),33],[Date.UTC(2018,2,9),41],[Date.UTC(2018,2,10),20],[Date.UTC(2018,2,11),34],[Date.UTC(2018,2,12),29],[Date.UTC(2018,2,13),14],[Date.UTC(2018,2,14),36],[Date.UTC(2018,2,15),31],[Date.UTC(2018,2,16),21],[Date.UTC(2018,2,17),9],[Date.UTC(2018,2,18),6],[Date.UTC(2018,2,19),21],[Date.UTC(2018,2,20),18],[Date.UTC(2018,2,21),25],[Date.UTC(2018,2,22),13],[Date.UTC(2018,2,23),10],[Date.UTC(2018,2,24),8],[Date.UTC(2018,2,25),1],[Date.UTC(2018,2,26),7],[Date.UTC(2018,2,27),7],[Date.UTC(2018,2,28),5],[Date.UTC(2018,2,29),14],[Date.UTC(2018,2,30),1],[Date.UTC(2018,2,31),1],[Date.UTC(2018,3,1),2],[Date.UTC(2018,3,2),17],[Date.UTC(2018,3,3),6],[Date.UTC(2018,3,4),21],[Date.UTC(2018,3,5),7],[Date.UTC(2018,3,6),12],[Date.UTC(2018,3,7),5],[Date.UTC(2018,3,8),6],[Date.UTC(2018,3,9),6],[Date.UTC(2018,3,10),8],[Date.UTC(2018,3,11),17],[Date.UTC(2018,3,12),7],[Date.UTC(2018,3,13),10],[Date.UTC(2018,3,14),5],[Date.UTC(2018,3,15),4],[Date.UTC(2018,3,16),4],[Date.UTC(2018,3,17),7],[Date.UTC(2018,3,18),9],[Date.UTC(2018,3,19),11],[Date.UTC(2018,3,20),11],[Date.UTC(2018,3,21),7],[Date.UTC(2018,3,22),1],[Date.UTC(2018,3,23),13],[Date.UTC(2018,3,24),16],[Date.UTC(2018,3,25),11],[Date.UTC(2018,3,26),29],[Date.UTC(2018,3,27),12],[Date.UTC(2018,3,28),4],[Date.UTC(2018,3,29),2],[Date.UTC(2018,3,30),22],[Date.UTC(2018,4,1),6],[Date.UTC(2018,4,2),18],[Date.UTC(2018,4,3),15],[Date.UTC(2018,4,4),21],[Date.UTC(2018,4,5),6],[Date.UTC(2018,4,6),3],[Date.UTC(2018,4,7),13],[Date.UTC(2018,4,8),10],[Date.UTC(2018,4,9),23],[Date.UTC(2018,4,10),21],[Date.UTC(2018,4,11),22],[Date.UTC(2018,4,12),14],[Date.UTC(2018,4,13),1],[Date.UTC(2018,4,14),12],[Date.UTC(2018,4,15),19],[Date.UTC(2018,4,16),25],[Date.UTC(2018,4,17),20],[Date.UTC(2018,4,18),17],[Date.UTC(2018,4,19),6],[Date.UTC(2018,4,20),3],[Date.UTC(2018,4,21),4],[Date.UTC(2018,4,22),6],[Date.UTC(2018,4,23),7],[Date.UTC(2018,4,24),10],[Date.UTC(2018,4,25),11],[Date.UTC(2018,4,26),7],[Date.UTC(2018,4,27),2],[Date.UTC(2018,4,28),7],[Date.UTC(2018,4,29),7],[Date.UTC(2018,4,30),10],[Date.UTC(2018,4,31),15],[Date.UTC(2018,5,1),16],[Date.UTC(2018,5,2),9],[Date.UTC(2018,5,3),4],[Date.UTC(2018,5,4),20],[Date.UTC(2018,5,5),14],[Date.UTC(2018,5,6),13],[Date.UTC(2018,5,7),4],[Date.UTC(2018,5,8),16],[Date.UTC(2018,5,9),3],[Date.UTC(2018,5,10),2],[Date.UTC(2018,5,11),9],[Date.UTC(2018,5,12),4],[Date.UTC(2018,5,13),12],[Date.UTC(2018,5,14),7],[Date.UTC(2018,5,15),3],[Date.UTC(2018,5,16),6],[Date.UTC(2018,5,17),2],[Date.UTC(2018,5,18),10],[Date.UTC(2018,5,19),26],[Date.UTC(2018,5,20),6],[Date.UTC(2018,5,21),6],[Date.UTC(2018,5,22),4],[Date.UTC(2018,5,23),12],[Date.UTC(2018,5,24),4],[Date.UTC(2018,5,25),4],[Date.UTC(2018,5,26),6],[Date.UTC(2018,5,27),8],[Date.UTC(2018,5,28),6],[Date.UTC(2018,5,29),8],[Date.UTC(2018,5,30),8],[Date.UTC(2018,6,1),5],[Date.UTC(2018,6,2),4],[Date.UTC(2018,6,3),5],[Date.UTC(2018,6,4),4],[Date.UTC(2018,6,5),3],[Date.UTC(2018,6,6),18],[Date.UTC(2018,6,7),6],[Date.UTC(2018,6,8),3],[Date.UTC(2018,6,9),16],[Date.UTC(2018,6,10),3],[Date.UTC(2018,6,11),11],[Date.UTC(2018,6,12),20],[Date.UTC(2018,6,13),21],[Date.UTC(2018,6,14),1],[Date.UTC(2018,6,15),4],[Date.UTC(2018,6,16),9],[Date.UTC(2018,6,17),12],[Date.UTC(2018,6,18),7],[Date.UTC(2018,6,19),4],[Date.UTC(2018,6,20),6],[Date.UTC(2018,6,21),4],[Date.UTC(2018,6,22),3],[Date.UTC(2018,6,23),6],[Date.UTC(2018,6,24),4],[Date.UTC(2018,6,25),9],[Date.UTC(2018,6,26),10],[Date.UTC(2018,6,27),5],[Date.UTC(2018,6,28),6],[Date.UTC(2018,6,29),7],[Date.UTC(2018,6,30),33],[Date.UTC(2018,6,31),9],[Date.UTC(2018,7,1),3],[Date.UTC(2018,7,2),8],[Date.UTC(2018,7,3),13],[Date.UTC(2018,7,4),7],[Date.UTC(2018,7,5),3],[Date.UTC(2018,7,6),12],[Date.UTC(2018,7,7),23],[Date.UTC(2018,7,8),12],[Date.UTC(2018,7,9),8],[Date.UTC(2018,7,10),15],[Date.UTC(2018,7,11),4],[Date.UTC(2018,7,12),1],[Date.UTC(2018,7,13),4],[Date.UTC(2018,7,14),5],[Date.UTC(2018,7,15),10],[Date.UTC(2018,7,16),9],[Date.UTC(2018,7,17),6],[Date.UTC(2018,7,18),8],[Date.UTC(2018,7,19),2],[Date.UTC(2018,7,20),6],[Date.UTC(2018,7,21),13],[Date.UTC(2018,7,22),4],[Date.UTC(2018,7,23),2],[Date.UTC(2018,7,24),11],[Date.UTC(2018,7,25),3],[Date.UTC(2018,7,26),3],[Date.UTC(2018,7,27),3],[Date.UTC(2018,7,28),5],[Date.UTC(2018,7,29),5],[Date.UTC(2018,7,30),12],[Date.UTC(2018,7,31),12],[Date.UTC(2018,8,1),6]]
            });


    };
    calls_chart_options.chart.renderTo = 'calls';
    calls_chart_options.chart.type = 'column';
    var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(calls_chart_options);
```

this is my first experience with highchart i have tried every combination from the net but no solution works for me,

here's the BiN!

[JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/hucitocata/1/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 0):

i did it myself what i was doing wrong is  i wasnt adding the type **datetime** in params

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'calls',
            type: 'column'
        },
        series: [{
            name:"Call Leads",
            data: [[Date.UTC(2017,8,1),10],[Date.UTC(2017,8,2),1],[Date.UTC(2017,8,3),1],[Date.UTC(2017,8,4),3],[Date.UTC(2017,8,5),6],[Date.UTC(2017,8,6),3],[Date.UTC(2017,8,7),4],[Date.UTC(2017,8,8),4],[Date.UTC(2017,8,9),0],[Date.UTC(2017,8,10),4],[Date.UTC(2017,8,11),9],[Date.UTC(2017,8,12),4],[Date.UTC(2017,8,13),6],[Date.UTC(2017,8,14),7],[Date.UTC(2017,8,15),5],[Date.UTC(2017,8,16),3],[Date.UTC(2017,8,17),3],[Date.UTC(2017,8,18),12],[Date.UTC(2017,8,19),8],[Date.UTC(2017,8,20),6],[Date.UTC(2017,8,21),6],[Date.UTC(2017,8,22),1],[Date.UTC(2017,8,23),1],[Date.UTC(2017,8,24),3],[Date.UTC(2017,8,25),6],[Date.UTC(2017,8,26),3],[Date.UTC(2017,8,27),4],[Date.UTC(2017,8,28),12],[Date.UTC(2017,8,29),5],[Date.UTC(2017,8,30),2],[Date.UTC(2017,9,1),0],[Date.UTC(2017,9,2),9],[Date.UTC(2017,9,3),7],[Date.UTC(2017,9,4),11],[Date.UTC(2017,9,5),10],[Date.UTC(2017,9,6),11],[Date.UTC(2017,9,7),4],[Date.UTC(2017,9,8),4],[Date.UTC(2017,9,9),16],[Date.UTC(2017,9,10),4],[Date.UTC(2017,9,11),7],[Date.UTC(2017,9,12),5],[Date.UTC(2017,9,13),10],[Date.UTC(2017,9,14),3],[Date.UTC(2017,9,15),1],[Date.UTC(2017,9,16),21],[Date.UTC(2017,9,17),7],[Date.UTC(2017,9,18),14],[Date.UTC(2017,9,19),9],[Date.UTC(2017,9,20),11],[Date.UTC(2017,9,21),3],[Date.UTC(2017,9,22),3],[Date.UTC(2017,9,23),25],[Date.UTC(2017,9,24),7],[Date.UTC(2017,9,25),9],[Date.UTC(2017,9,26),11],[Date.UTC(2017,9,27),18],[Date.UTC(2017,9,28),4],[Date.UTC(2017,9,29),2],[Date.UTC(2017,9,30),10],[Date.UTC(2017,9,31),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,1),5],[Date.UTC(2017,10,2),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,3),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,4),5],[Date.UTC(2017,10,5),6],[Date.UTC(2017,10,6),1],[Date.UTC(2017,10,7),6],[Date.UTC(2017,10,8),6],[Date.UTC(2017,10,9),3],[Date.UTC(2017,10,10),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,11),2],[Date.UTC(2017,10,12),1],[Date.UTC(2017,10,13),1],[Date.UTC(2017,10,14),8],[Date.UTC(2017,10,15),8],[Date.UTC(2017,10,16),6],[Date.UTC(2017,10,17),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,18),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,19),1],[Date.UTC(2017,10,20),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,21),5],[Date.UTC(2017,10,22),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,23),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,24),1],[Date.UTC(2017,10,25),5],[Date.UTC(2017,10,26),2],[Date.UTC(2017,10,27),4],[Date.UTC(2017,10,28),2],[Date.UTC(2017,10,29),10],[Date.UTC(2017,10,30),2],[Date.UTC(2017,11,1),4],[Date.UTC(2017,11,2),5],[Date.UTC(2017,11,3),3],[Date.UTC(2017,11,4),2],[Date.UTC(2017,11,5),7],[Date.UTC(2017,11,6),2],[Date.UTC(2017,11,7),3],[Date.UTC(2017,11,8),10],[Date.UTC(2017,11,9),1],[Date.UTC(2017,11,10),0],[Date.UTC(2017,11,11),6],[Date.UTC(2017,11,12),3],[Date.UTC(2017,11,13),4],[Date.UTC(2017,11,14),5],[Date.UTC(2017,11,15),3],[Date.UTC(2017,11,16),3],[Date.UTC(2017,11,17),0],[Date.UTC(2017,11,18),1],[Date.UTC(2017,11,19),1],[Date.UTC(2017,11,20),8],[Date.UTC(2017,11,21),9],[Date.UTC(2017,11,22),3],[Date.UTC(2017,11,23),1],[Date.UTC(2017,11,24),4],[Date.UTC(2017,11,25),1],[Date.UTC(2017,11,26),6],[Date.UTC(2017,11,27),7],[Date.UTC(2017,11,28),3],[Date.UTC(2017,11,29),3],[Date.UTC(2017,11,30),0],[Date.UTC(2017,11,31),5],[Date.UTC(2018,0,1),2],[Date.UTC(2018,0,2),2],[Date.UTC(2018,0,3),5],[Date.UTC(2018,0,4),10],[Date.UTC(2018,0,5),16],[Date.UTC(2018,0,6),2],[Date.UTC(2018,0,7),0],[Date.UTC(2018,0,8),4],[Date.UTC(2018,0,9),4],[Date.UTC(2018,0,10),2],[Date.UTC(2018,0,11),3],[Date.UTC(2018,0,12),2],[Date.UTC(2018,0,13),4],[Date.UTC(2018,0,14),3],[Date.UTC(2018,0,15),5],[Date.UTC(2018,0,16),17],[Date.UTC(2018,0,17),18],[Date.UTC(2018,0,18),13],[Date.UTC(2018,0,19),9],[Date.UTC(2018,0,20),7],[Date.UTC(2018,0,21),2],[Date.UTC(2018,0,22),16],[Date.UTC(2018,0,23),19],[Date.UTC(2018,0,24),24],[Date.UTC(2018,0,25),23],[Date.UTC(2018,0,26),33],[Date.UTC(2018,0,27),13],[Date.UTC(2018,0,28),1],[Date.UTC(2018,0,29),11],[Date.UTC(2018,0,30),27],[Date.UTC(2018,0,31),48],[Date.UTC(2018,1,1),23],[Date.UTC(2018,1,2),24],[Date.UTC(2018,1,3),9],[Date.UTC(2018,1,4),1],[Date.UTC(2018,1,5),6],[Date.UTC(2018,1,6),20],[Date.UTC(2018,1,7),22],[Date.UTC(2018,1,8),22],[Date.UTC(2018,1,9),16],[Date.UTC(2018,1,10),9],[Date.UTC(2018,1,11),8],[Date.UTC(2018,1,12),18],[Date.UTC(2018,1,13),11],[Date.UTC(2018,1,14),20],[Date.UTC(2018,1,15),14],[Date.UTC(2018,1,16),14],[Date.UTC(2018,1,17),15],[Date.UTC(2018,1,18),5],[Date.UTC(2018,1,19),14],[Date.UTC(2018,1,20),25],[Date.UTC(2018,1,21),17],[Date.UTC(2018,1,22),23],[Date.UTC(2018,1,23),20],[Date.UTC(2018,1,24),4],[Date.UTC(2018,1,25),6],[Date.UTC(2018,1,26),22],[Date.UTC(2018,1,27),21],[Date.UTC(2018,1,28),23],[Date.UTC(2018,2,1),15],[Date.UTC(2018,2,2),8],[Date.UTC(2018,2,3),6],[Date.UTC(2018,2,4),6],[Date.UTC(2018,2,5),20],[Date.UTC(2018,2,6),24],[Date.UTC(2018,2,7),36],[Date.UTC(2018,2,8),33],[Date.UTC(2018,2,9),41],[Date.UTC(2018,2,10),20],[Date.UTC(2018,2,11),34],[Date.UTC(2018,2,12),29],[Date.UTC(2018,2,13),14],[Date.UTC(2018,2,14),36],[Date.UTC(2018,2,15),31],[Date.UTC(2018,2,16),21],[Date.UTC(2018,2,17),9],[Date.UTC(2018,2,18),6],[Date.UTC(2018,2,19),21],[Date.UTC(2018,2,20),18],[Date.UTC(2018,2,21),25],[Date.UTC(2018,2,22),13],[Date.UTC(2018,2,23),10],[Date.UTC(2018,2,24),8],[Date.UTC(2018,2,25),1],[Date.UTC(2018,2,26),7],[Date.UTC(2018,2,27),7],[Date.UTC(2018,2,28),5],[Date.UTC(2018,2,29),14],[Date.UTC(2018,2,30),1],[Date.UTC(2018,2,31),1],[Date.UTC(2018,3,1),2],[Date.UTC(2018,3,2),17],[Date.UTC(2018,3,3),6],[Date.UTC(2018,3,4),21],[Date.UTC(2018,3,5),7],[Date.UTC(2018,3,6),12],[Date.UTC(2018,3,7),5],[Date.UTC(2018,3,8),6],[Date.UTC(2018,3,9),6],[Date.UTC(2018,3,10),8],[Date.UTC(2018,3,11),17],[Date.UTC(2018,3,12),7],[Date.UTC(2018,3,13),10],[Date.UTC(2018,3,14),5],[Date.UTC(2018,3,15),4],[Date.UTC(2018,3,16),4],[Date.UTC(2018,3,17),7],[Date.UTC(2018,3,18),9],[Date.UTC(2018,3,19),11],[Date.UTC(2018,3,20),11],[Date.UTC(2018,3,21),7],[Date.UTC(2018,3,22),1],[Date.UTC(2018,3,23),13],[Date.UTC(2018,3,24),16],[Date.UTC(2018,3,25),11],[Date.UTC(2018,3,26),29],[Date.UTC(2018,3,27),12],[Date.UTC(2018,3,28),4],[Date.UTC(2018,3,29),2],[Date.UTC(2018,3,30),22],[Date.UTC(2018,4,1),6],[Date.UTC(2018,4,2),18],[Date.UTC(2018,4,3),15],[Date.UTC(2018,4,4),21],[Date.UTC(2018,4,5),6],[Date.UTC(2018,4,6),3],[Date.UTC(2018,4,7),13],[Date.UTC(2018,4,8),10],[Date.UTC(2018,4,9),23],[Date.UTC(2018,4,10),21],[Date.UTC(2018,4,11),22],[Date.UTC(2018,4,12),14],[Date.UTC(2018,4,13),1],[Date.UTC(2018,4,14),12],[Date.UTC(2018,4,15),19],[Date.UTC(2018,4,16),25],[Date.UTC(2018,4,17),20],[Date.UTC(2018,4,18),17],[Date.UTC(2018,4,19),6],[Date.UTC(2018,4,20),3],[Date.UTC(2018,4,21),4],[Date.UTC(2018,4,22),6],[Date.UTC(2018,4,23),7],[Date.UTC(2018,4,24),10],[Date.UTC(2018,4,25),11],[Date.UTC(2018,4,26),7],[Date.UTC(2018,4,27),2],[Date.UTC(2018,4,28),7],[Date.UTC(2018,4,29),7],[Date.UTC(2018,4,30),10],[Date.UTC(2018,4,31),15],[Date.UTC(2018,5,1),16],[Date.UTC(2018,5,2),9],[Date.UTC(2018,5,3),4],[Date.UTC(2018,5,4),20],[Date.UTC(2018,5,5),14],[Date.UTC(2018,5,6),13],[Date.UTC(2018,5,7),4],[Date.UTC(2018,5,8),16],[Date.UTC(2018,5,9),3],[Date.UTC(2018,5,10),2],[Date.UTC(2018,5,11),9],[Date.UTC(2018,5,12),4],[Date.UTC(2018,5,13),12],[Date.UTC(2018,5,14),7],[Date.UTC(2018,5,15),3],[Date.UTC(2018,5,16),6],[Date.UTC(2018,5,17),2],[Date.UTC(2018,5,18),10],[Date.UTC(2018,5,19),26],[Date.UTC(2018,5,20),6],[Date.UTC(2018,5,21),6],[Date.UTC(2018,5,22),4],[Date.UTC(2018,5,23),12],[Date.UTC(2018,5,24),4],[Date.UTC(2018,5,25),4],[Date.UTC(2018,5,26),6],[Date.UTC(2018,5,27),8],[Date.UTC(2018,5,28),6],[Date.UTC(2018,5,29),8],[Date.UTC(2018,5,30),8],[Date.UTC(2018,6,1),5],[Date.UTC(2018,6,2),4],[Date.UTC(2018,6,3),5],[Date.UTC(2018,6,4),4],[Date.UTC(2018,6,5),3],[Date.UTC(2018,6,6),18],[Date.UTC(2018,6,7),6],[Date.UTC(2018,6,8),3],[Date.UTC(2018,6,9),16],[Date.UTC(2018,6,10),3],[Date.UTC(2018,6,11),11],[Date.UTC(2018,6,12),20],[Date.UTC(2018,6,13),21],[Date.UTC(2018,6,14),1],[Date.UTC(2018,6,15),4],[Date.UTC(2018,6,16),9],[Date.UTC(2018,6,17),12],[Date.UTC(2018,6,18),7],[Date.UTC(2018,6,19),4],[Date.UTC(2018,6,20),6],[Date.UTC(2018,6,21),4],[Date.UTC(2018,6,22),3],[Date.UTC(2018,6,23),6],[Date.UTC(2018,6,24),4],[Date.UTC(2018,6,25),9],[Date.UTC(2018,6,26),10],[Date.UTC(2018,6,27),5],[Date.UTC(2018,6,28),6],[Date.UTC(2018,6,29),7],[Date.UTC(2018,6,30),33],[Date.UTC(2018,6,31),9],[Date.UTC(2018,7,1),3],[Date.UTC(2018,7,2),8],[Date.UTC(2018,7,3),13],[Date.UTC(2018,7,4),7],[Date.UTC(2018,7,5),3],[Date.UTC(2018,7,6),12],[Date.UTC(2018,7,7),23],[Date.UTC(2018,7,8),12],[Date.UTC(2018,7,9),8],[Date.UTC(2018,7,10),15],[Date.UTC(2018,7,11),4],[Date.UTC(2018,7,12),1],[Date.UTC(2018,7,13),4],[Date.UTC(2018,7,14),5],[Date.UTC(2018,7,15),10],[Date.UTC(2018,7,16),9],[Date.UTC(2018,7,17),6],[Date.UTC(2018,7,18),8],[Date.UTC(2018,7,19),2],[Date.UTC(2018,7,20),6],[Date.UTC(2018,7,21),13],[Date.UTC(2018,7,22),4],[Date.UTC(2018,7,23),2],[Date.UTC(2018,7,24),11],[Date.UTC(2018,7,25),3],[Date.UTC(2018,7,26),3],[Date.UTC(2018,7,27),3],[Date.UTC(2018,7,28),5],[Date.UTC(2018,7,29),5],[Date.UTC(2018,7,30),12],[Date.UTC(2018,7,31),12],[Date.UTC(2018,8,1),6]],
        }],
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            labels: {
                format: '{value:%Y-%b-%e}'
            }
        }
    });
```

hope this helps someone else!